# Method linked with Subscribe in EventAggregator pattern is never fired

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism, eventaggregator

I have two ViewModels called ViewModelOne and ViewModelTwo.

I also have a class called SelectedTileChangedEvent in my Infrastructure Project. Here is the code:

```
public class SelectedTileChangedEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<int> { }
```

In ViewModelOne:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<SelectedTileChangedEvent>().Publish(1);
```

After calling this Publish method instance of ViewModelOne is destroyed.

In ViewModelTwo's constructor:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<SelectedTileChangedEvent>().Subscribe(SelectedTileChanged);

private void SelectedTileChanged(int selectedTileId)
{
    //some code
}
```

But the SelectedTileChanged Method is never fired.

I have tried the following two possible solutions:

1. I have passed in an extra parameter to Subscribe Method as `keepSubscriberReferenceAlive = true`. So, my code looks like:

   ```
   _eventAggregator.GetEvent<SelectedTileChangedEvent>().Subscribe(SelectedTileChanged, true);
   ```
2. I thought that the instance of Publisher is always destroyed before any Subscriber can listen to the Event. So, I Implemented `IRegionMemberLifetime` on ViewModelOne as follows:

   ```
   private bool KeepAlive()
   {
        get { return true; }
   }
   ```

Both the above mentioned attempts does not give me the required result.

I really need to subscribe to the SelectedTileChangedEvent and thus I would like my SelectedTileChanged Method to be called from ViewModelTwo....

Thanks

Comment: Most probably you are not using the very same instance of the event aggregator, rather you have two distinct instances. Show how you pass the aggregator to both view models.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I pass the IEventAggregator to the constructor of the ViewModelOne as well as ViewModelTwo.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about the very same instance.

Comment: `CompositePresentationEvent` is obsolete in Prism 5.  Replace its use with `PubSubEvent`.

Comment: @Jason I m using prism 4.1, does it support pubsubevent?

Comment: No, only version 5. As Wiktor has suggested, you need to post more details on how you pass (and receive) the aggregator.

Comment: @Jason I have already posted all the details in my question. I have IEventAggregator in the constructor of each viewmodel. And I never call any constructor explicitly. I just register the regions and it might be calling the constructor automatically.

Comment: Put breakpoints in the constructors of each view model, and when the first constructor is hit, right-click the eventAggregator paramter in the Locals pane, and click "Make Object ID".  Make a note of the object ID that gets assigned.  When the second constructor is called, see if the eventAggregator has the same ID.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I get the same value in both the cases.

Comment: Are you sure you are subscribing to the event before the event is being published? Put a breakpoint on the line that publishes the event. Before it executes the Publish method drill into the `_eventAggregator` object. You should be able to see an events dictionary containing the `SelectedTileChangedEvent`. Drill into the `Value` of that item in the dictionary and you should be able to see the number of active subscriptions. Confirm that you are seeing at least one active subscriber.

Comment: @Jason Yes, I can see Count = 1.

Comment: @Jason Also, when I subscribe to the event I can see count = 2.

Comment: @Jason Just before I subscribe to the event I can see count = 1

Comment: Before you subscribe, you should see zero subscriptions for the event. If you are seeing one subscription already, something else is subscribing elsewhere.  Perhaps that is interfering with your event?

Comment: I have another event, i mean class called SelectedMenuItemChanged and probably the same instance of that eventAggregator is subscribing to that event.